# Why is an exception thrown when an @ManagedProperty is referenced?

Tags: jsf, javabeans, icefaces

I have a JSF web application with a view-scoped bean and a session-scoped bean. I'd like to modify the session bean's members from the view bean, and I followed [this](http://balusc.blogspot.com.br/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#InjectingManagedBeansInEachOther) guide from a certain well-known JSF guy, but I can't seem to get it to work without a runtime exception. The reference to the managed session bean, "home" is null when referenced, similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9036266/managedproperty-not-working) except I've already followed the advice of the accepted answer.

```
package brian.canadaShipping;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean(name= "requestBean")
@ViewScoped
public class CpstcRequestBean implements Serializable {

@ManagedProperty(value="#{home}")
private CpstcHomeBean homeBean;


public CpstcHomeBean getHomeBean() {
    return homeBean;
}


public void setHomeBean(CpstcHomeBean homeBean) {
    this.homeBean = homeBean;
}


private static final long serialVersionUID = -5066913533772933899L;

public String testVar = "hello world";
private boolean displayOutput = false;

public boolean isDisplayOutput() {
    return displayOutput;
}


public void setDisplayOutput(boolean displayOutput) {
    this.displayOutput = displayOutput;
}


public String getTestVar() {
    return testVar;
}


public void setTestVar(String testVar) {
    this.testVar = testVar;
}


public CpstcRequestBean()
{
    System.out.println("TEST: " + homeBean.toString());
    System.out.println("Hello, ResuestBean!");
}

}
```

The first bit of my "home" bean is as follows:

```
@ManagedBean(name= "home")
@SessionScoped
public class CpstcHomeBean implements Serializable {
    ...
```

**UPDATE:** I've followed Jordan's suggestions and I have the following in my view-scoped bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name= "requestBean")
@ViewScoped
public class CpstcRequestBean implements Serializable {

@Inject @Named("home") CpstcHomeBean homeBean;

public CpstcHomeBean getHomeBean() {
    return homeBean;
}


public void setHomeBean(CpstcHomeBean homeBean) {
    this.homeBean = homeBean;
}

public CpstcRequestBean()
{
    System.out.println("TEST: " + homeBean.toString());
    System.out.println("Hello, ResuestBean!");
}
...
```

as well as this in my session-scoped bean:

```
@Named("home")
@SessionScoped
public class CpstcHomeBean implements Serializable {
...
```

yet my "home" bean reference is still null. Any ideas?

**UPDATE 2:** It turns out that you must use @Named in both classes, not just the injected class. My web app now loads but some elements are blank. In my console log, I see, "Target Unreachable, identifier 'home' resolved to null." I'm running on Tomcat 7, if that affects things. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can either change your session bean's @ManagedBean to @Named and then just inject it into your view scoped bean OR you can reference the session bean as is like this:

```
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
private CpstcHomeBean homeBean = (CpstcHomeBean)  fc.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(fc, "#{home}", CpstcHomeBean.class);
```

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean, write:

    @Named("home")

instead of:

    @ManagedBean(name="home")

? I know this seems like a basic "RTFM" question, but [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Named.html) API isn't so clear on its usage in JSF. [This example] just uses, "@Named" but I'm not sure where the name of the bean is defined then, if it's not a parameter of the annotation and if it's not defined in faces-config.xml.

Comment: Yes : ) Then use @Inject instead of ManagedProperty

Comment: I can't seem to import the "Named" class. Eclipse suggests javax.faces.event.NamedEvent instead... Trying the alternate method using FacesContext yields, "The type javax.el.ELException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files."

Comment: import javax.inject.Named and javax.inject.Inject

Comment: I'm still getting NullPointerException on the home bean reference. :-(

Comment: StackOverflow's comment system is choking on my @ references so please see the updated question.

Comment: I fixed the NullPointerException, but now I'm getting a different error at runtime when the page loads. The bean is now not visible from the xhtml file! (see OP)

Comment: Try removing Named after Inject

Comment: That fixed the console output, but I'm afraid that components are still failing to render, and HomeBean doesn't appear to be constructed.

Comment: BTW, I'm reading [the answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986847/java-ee-6-javax-annotation-managedbean-vs-javax-inject-named-vs-javax-faces) and it seems like CDI annotations which you've recommended don't work natively with Tomcat. I tried running it on some modified Tomcat server which supposedly supported CDI (TomcatEE), but the project wouldn't even build. Should I migrate to a more robust backend?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17428/discussion-between-stockb-and-jordan-denison)

Comment: Did you create the "requestBean" in faces-config.xml too?